# Object spread operator: Set property to be updated via payload

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, vuex

Code snippet:

```
updateSelectedAreaColor: (state, payload) => {
state.selectedArea = { ...state.selectedArea, color: payload };
},
```

I'm updating the property **color** of the object **state.selectedArea** with a payload. Instead of hard-coding the property to be updated, I would like to set the property through my **payload**. 
 For example:

```
updateSelectedAreaColor: (state, payload) => {
state.selectedArea = { ...state.selectedArea, payload.target: payload.value };
},
```

However, this code throws an error. Does anyone know how I can set the value to be updated via the payload?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dynamic properties go into brackets:

```
 updateSelectedAreaColor: (state, payload) => {
    state.selectedArea = { ...state.selectedArea, [payload.target]: payload.value };
 },
```

However I would prefer:

```
 updateSelectedAreaColor: (state, payload) => {
   state.selectedArea = { ...state.selectedArea,  ...payload};
 },
```

That way, you can easily change multiple props at the same time:

```
 updateSelectedAreaColor(this.state, { color: "green", backgroundColor: "red" });
```

Comment: Why mutating the `state` ?

Comment: @arup why not?!

Comment: Because you should not.

Comment: @arup thats the most senseless argument i've ever heard.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that I was referring to vuex. I've added the tag. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @JonasWilms Why do we tell people in React community don't mutate the state, create a new object? I don't know where it is senseless. You really didn't get my point. Mutation is not really good thing, and it is not related to React. It is true in all programming.

Comment: @arup because when using React, React itself updates the state and causes a rerender, if you mutate the state there, you won't cause a rerender which is why you have to call `setState` to make it work properly. Every stateful framework / whatever has a place where the state gets mutated, however those are well defined. Without knowing the framework that the OP uses it is hard to tell wether mutating `state` is a good thing or not, and I don't give React specific advices if the OP is not using React.

Comment: @JonasWilms I agree with you. But mutating the object to me felt very wrong. Anyway thanks for taking time to write the answer and comments to clear your thought and my misunderstanding. :)